# Why do I get errors when creating a RHEL 8.3 VM on Windows Server 2012 r2 Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: hyper-v, redhat-enterprise-linux, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2012 r2 machine. I am attempting to create a VM with RHEL 8.3 and am running into issues. I have tried creating both Generation 1 and Generation 2 VMs and neither have worked.

When I select Generation 1, I get the following error:

[image: Errors on Generation 1 RHEL VM]

When I attempt to create the VM as Generation 2, I get the following error:
[image: Errors on Generation 2 RHEL]
\After doing some research, I turned off EnableSecureBoot via Powershell:

```
Get-VMFirmWare -VMName "MyVmName" | Select-Object *
Set-VMFirmWare -VMName "MyVmName" -EnableSecureBoot On/Off
```

But I still get the same error.

Is there something I'm missing here or a workaround for my issue. I need to get the VM up and running with RHEL 8.3.

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: If the VM fails to boot the RHEL image, make sure you've changed the secure boot template to Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority. For more details, you could refer to the following article:https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/install-rhel8-hyperv#

Comment: There are some notes here for 8.1, not sure if 8.3 is officially supported on 2012r2. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/Supported-CentOS-and-Red-Hat-Enterprise-Linux-virtual-machines-on-Hyper-V